# Github: Push additional commit to pull request

Tags: git, command-line, github, pull-request

I made a pull request, but now I need to push an additional commit to this pull request. Github says that:

> You can add more commits to this pull request by pushing to the x4e925e4 branch on myaccount/repo.

How do I achieve this via the command line?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
git push origin master:x4e925e4
```

If you want to push from another branch, just change the "master" bit.

Once the pull request is done, if this branch is not automatically deleted, you can delete it with:

```
git push origin :x4e925e4
```

Comment: What does the `master:` part do?

Comment: It tells git that you want to push the local `master` branch on the remote `x4e925e4` branch. See `git-push(1)`.

Comment: Ah. But if the user is one the `x4e925e4` branch, they should not push master.

Comment: If you want to create a temporary branch, you are indeed right.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm. My take on this is

```
git checkout x4e925e4
// add commits
git push origin x4e925e4
```

My opinion on best practice: you should create a topic branch specifically for every pull request, with a reasonable name. Some people prefer that you namespace it with your github userid. That way they can freely check it out locally to try it out, with less fear of branch name collision.

So I usually name my pull request branches something like

```
claybridges-do-the-things
```